# Converting a JWT with javascript results in a wrong expiration date

Tags: javascript, date, jwt

This is my JWT:

```
"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTgxMDM1MTcsIm5iZiI6MTU5ODEwMzUxNywianRpIjoiNzcxMjcyZjAtODQxNC00NDU5LTg5OGQtNzJiNGMzNGMyZGZjIiwiZXhwIjoxNTk4MTA0NDE3LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6Im1heHBvd2VyIiwiZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwidXNlcl9jbGFpbXMiOiJtYXhwb3dlciJ9.ilycgqpuyvnnHm63JPD9a9r090-Bu__uj2auEFnk3HA"
```

I get this from my Flask API and try to decode it like this:

```
const result = VueJwtDecode.decode(data.data.access_token);
console.log(result);
const expirationDate = result.exp;
console.log(expirationDate)
```

This results in a number (miliseconds?)

```
1598104755
```

I tried to convert this back to a normal Dateformat.

```
const expirationDate = new Date(result.exp)
console.log(expirationDate);

Mon Jan 19 1970 12:55:04 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

This is obviously wrong. What am I doing wrong and why does this result in the year 1970?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1598104755 is a number of *seconds* since the epoch in 1970.

Unlike some languages, JavaScript's Date is based on milliseconds, so you'll need to multiply by 1000 before passing to `new Date`:

```js
console.log(
  new Date(
    1598104755 * 1000
  )
);
```

Comment: thank you, that was quick ;-). Will accept your answer in some minutes